# How to keep an immutable borrow while changing data?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a renderer for my abstract node system.

Each node is on a circuit, which looks like:

```rust
struct Circuit<'a> {
  nodes: Vec<Node>,
  connections: Vec<Connection<'a>>,
}
```

Where each nodes contains some arbitrary data, and a connection connects those two nodes.

```rust
struct Connection<'a> {
  from: &'a Node,
  to: &'a Node,
}
```

In one instance, I'm trying to mutably iterate over `Circuit.nodes` and change some data, while still keeping the refences to `Node` inside `Connections`. I want the `Connection` references to still hold the reference to the same `Node` structs, but point to the updated data after the mutable borrow.

But with this setup, I get an `cannot borrow 'circuit.nodes' as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable` error.

I have tried to use `RefCell` and a `Mutex`, but to no success. No resource I could find explained this problem well.

Comment: Please provide more context, including a minimal reproducible example and what you tried regarding `RefCell`.

Comment: Have you read [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](/q/32300132/2189130)

Comment: In your case, the easiest solution is probably to change `Connection` so that it holds the indices of the nodes in the `nodes` vector instead of holding direct references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to wrap your Nodes in a [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) (or [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) if in multithreaded contexts),
that way connections and the circuit can share ownership over the nodes

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
fn main() {
    let a = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node { data: "a".into() }));
    let b = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node { data: "b".into() }));
    let conn = Connection {
        from: a.clone(),
        to: b.clone(),
    };
    let cir = Circuit {
        nodes: vec![a.clone(), b.clone()],
        connections: vec![conn],
    };
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    data: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Circuit {
  nodes: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
  connections: Vec<Connection>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Connection {
  from: Rc<RefCell<Node>>,
  to: Rc<RefCell<Node>>,
}
```

Comment: That actually works! Thank you so much, never would have i though about wrapping it twice like that. Is there anyway to prevent `.borrow()` everywhere in my code, or is it something i need to live with?

Comment: Yea you'll often see `Rc/Arc` and `RefCell/Mutex` used in combination to allow for shared mutable access.
As for getting rid of `.borrow()`, only if you don't need mutable access to the `Node`s in that case you could drop all the `RefCell`s